# How do I delete my question?

Tags: support, deletion

I tried to contribute to the math forum by providing a question and an answer that I thought was insightful, I am getting a lot of down votes without any explanations. I want to take my question down. How do I do it? Here is the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380693/the-thought-process-of-derivatives-explained-intermediate-calculus-derivative/380694?noredirect=1#comment815243_380694)

Comment: You cannot delete the question because it has an upvoted answer. You can, if you wish, delete your *answer*. This will recover any points lost to the downvotes. Alternatively, you can make your answer community-wiki (by editing and checking the appropriate box): this will prevent any future votes on the question from affecting your numerical reputation.

Comment: There's a functionality in SE that you can ask a question and answer your own question simultaneously. I read about this somewhere in FAQ it said it is welcome. But in fact it's not welcome for many questions and many users. I saw many down-voted question-answer posts in MSE and Askubuntu. I think it's not welcome in many other SE sites too. Maybe wikiproof and other wiki-pages with free editing access are better places for question-answer posts.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was welcome as well. I was very surprised at the down voting. How can someone be down voted when their intention is to contribute; it was not for my benefit (I gave up a lot of my time to write up the answer for that question to make it as coherent as possible). I can understand if my answer was wrong and therefore it would be detrimental, but then people should comment and explain the errors. This makes me not want to contribute again.